# No overload for 'method' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, compiler-errors

I am trying to build a program that, once the button was click, every 5 second will perform the function (OnTimed).

Below is the code so far:

```
private void bntCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    DispatcherTimer t1 = new DispatcherTimer();
    t1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);
    t1.IsEnabled = true;
    t1.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimed);
    t1.Start();
}

void OnTimed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{

    imgCapture.Source = imgVideo.Source;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Helper.SaveImageCapture((BitmapSource)imgCapture.Source);
}
```

When i run the code, it show the error:

> "No overload for 'method' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The signature of the event-handler method isn't compatible with the delegate type.

Subsribers to the [`DispatcherTimer.Tick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.tick.aspx) event must be of the [`EventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) delegate type, which is declared as:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Try this instead:

```
void OnTimed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you using Windows phone 8.1 then you need the following

```
private void OnTimed(object sender, object e) {
      // You Code Here
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Method OnTimed has to declared like this:

```
 private void OnTimed(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // Do something
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it might be a little bit late, but i just wanted to throw in a bit more for anyone with this problem:

```
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Method);

public void Method(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Do Something
}
```

solves the Problem.

> It can also be written like this: **timer.Tick += Method;**

```
timer.Tick += Method;

public void Method(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Do Something
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

[Dispatcher.Tick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.tick.aspx) is simple EventHandler:

> public event EventHandler Tick;

So EventHandler parameters should be:

```
void OnTimed(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Not the

```
void OnTimed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

---

Looks like you a bit overlooked around the [System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx) event
which is:

```
public event ElapsedEventHandler Elapsed

public delegate void ElapsedEventHandler(
    Object sender,
    ElapsedEventArgs e
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a custom winforms control for digitalPersona fingerprint recognition.

When I tried to overload the 'OnComplete' method it would come up with 'No overload...'

```
private void FingerprintVerificationControl_OnComplete(object control, DPFP.FeatureSet featureSet, DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus eventHandlerStatus)
```

This is what it looked like.

I looked into the assembly and I noticed that third parameter had the 'ref' keyword attached to it. I added it in my code and it worked:

```
private void FingerprintVerificationControl_OnComplete(object control, DPFP.FeatureSet featureSet, ref DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus eventHandlerStatus)
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, this has nothing to do with the original question (which has already been sufficiently answered).

Comment: Ye but I googled the title of this post and I found the answer being a different one than the one selected here. Can it be that hard for someone else to encounter the same problem like I did? I didn't post it for rep or w/e - I want to help others, that's the whole point for this site..

Comment: The correct course of action would be to create your own question fitting your problem, complete with the right tags (Windows Forms, etc. ..) and answer it yourself.