# Validate input empty textbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to validate textboxes for empty values. If the textbox is empty and loses focus, an error has to show and the textbox has to receive focus again.

Reading about this I came across the Validating event, which can be cancelled through e.Cancel. However when I try to do this, I get an error message.

My code:

```cs
private void CheckInput(CancelEventArgs e, TextBox tb)
{
   ErrorProvider error = new ErrorProvider();
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
   {
      error.SetError(tb, "*");
      e.Cancel = true;
   }

   else
   {
      error.SetError(tb, "");
   }
}

private void tbTitel_Validated(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    CheckInput(e, tbTitel);

}
```

And the error I get is the following:

**Error 1   No overload for 'tbTitel_Validated' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'**

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The validating uses this delegate:

```
private void tbTitel_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
}
```

The validated event uses this:

```
private void tbTitel_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

You want to use the *[Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* event (you should link you eventhandler to the validating event, not the *validated* event. This way you can cancel it.

You probably clicked the validating first and copy/paste/selected the eventhandler name into the validated event. (designer)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to execute your checks, not the `Validated` event.

The two events have different signatures. The `Validated` event receives the simple `EventArgs` argument, while the Validating event receives the `CancelEventArgs` argument that could be used to revert the focus switch.

Said that, it seems that your logic is wrong.

```
// error if string is null or empty
// if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
{
   error.SetError(tb, "*");
   e.Cancel = true;
}
else
{
   error.SetError(tb, "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed the problem. I do however have other problems now but I will try to fix them as go. :)

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs, because tbTitel_Validated doesnt have `CancelEventArgs` in its signature.

Take a look at this thread for further information:
[No overload for 'method' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067246/no-overload-for-method-matches-delegate-system-eventhandler)

Conclusion: Use `tbTitel_Validating` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Alwasy use validation statements at Object.Validated event handler**

Likewise:

```
 private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please use valid data input!!");
            }
        }
```